# Bundle all dependencies into a single import file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I've been wondering. Is there any library that allows me to bundle every dependency I use into a single bundle so I can import everything from it?

For example:

```
import x from "react-native-x"
import y from "react-native-y"
import z from "react-native-z"
import { View } from "react-native"
import React from "react"
import a from "./a"
import b from "./../../b"
```

Into this:

```
import {
  x,
  y,
  z
  View,
  React,
  a,
  b
} from "./bundle"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is **absolute paths**.

Here are a few materials to look:

- https://goenning.net/2017/07/21/how-to-avoid-relative-path-hell-javascript-typescript-projects/
- https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/10/07/absolute-paths-javascript/
- Webapck docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Search for terms like absolute path, alias webpack.

But, if that's not the case, one thing you can do is:

1. Create a folder called bundle
2. Create an index.js file and export whatever you want from there
3. Use it as your main reference to import from.

// bundle/index.js

```
export * from "react-native-x"
export {View} from "react-native"
export * from "./a"
export * from "./../../b"
```

Some reference for exports:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

```
// Aggregating modules
export * from …; // does not set the default export
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { default } from …;
```

Hope it helps.